# Is there a word for a person who takes on his own challenge?

Tags: word-choice

A challenger? I'm not a native English speaker but I think when people hear that word they naturally assume the challenge is not set by the challenger. I don't want to imply that.

If no such word exists, a synonym (informal if necessary) for a courageous person (in one word) would be the next best thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't think of a word for a person who would specifically choose to face challenges, but there are several names for roles that essentially boil down to that:

- **Adventurer**
- **Daredevil**
- **Voyager**
- **Thrill-seeker**

*Challenger* isn't quite wrong too - as one can challenge the inanimate too: a mountain-climber, who challenged the K-2.

Comment: Not too wild about the synonyms though. These imply that the person who takes the challenge enjoys 'thrills'. I'm rather looking for a word that implies that the person undertakes it out of necessity (because that person understands the need to challenge himself in order to attain a certain goal).

Comment: @Bentley4: **Hero**?

Comment: That indeed fits this description. But the word `hero` implies that what the person did held extreme risks. I'm looking for a milder term (for a person taking small to moderate risks). Using 'hero' in case of a small risk could have an unwanted redicularising effect (sarcasm).

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps **[quester](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/quester)**

*[Quest](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/quester)* is defined as

> a long and difficult effort to find or do something

Quests way be self directed or set by others.

Comment: Nice. However I'm going to use the word 'challenge' in any case for the project I'm doing (I think it's more fitting because quest implies a long duration, while challenge does not and I don't want to imply long duration). If I then use 'Quester' to describe a person who takes on the challenge than people will immediately think: why not take quest instead of challenge. And I want it to be clear without needing to clarify this over and over. So I can't use that either.